# Rich text editor for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add a rich text editor to my website. This my first time doing this, so which rich text editor do you suggest I use? I need one that is fully functional and easy to integrate with a rails application, also I am using prototype.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for correcting my question and i think you have voted down me too what is the reason for voting me down so that i should not repeat it onwards

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I can suggest you try to make your question titles a bit better in future. Your original title was basically "I have a problem" rather than a quick description of the problem. We know you have a problem, that's why you're posting a question :)

Comment: Also, your questions will be easier to read with a few more full stops - break your thoughts into shorter sentences.

Comment: @Blorgbeard yeah you are rite i should not write the title like that now i got it from now i will be careful about this and thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an editor like TinyMCE as the posters above have recommended. However IMHO the HTML generated by these editors tends to get messy. I would suggest you look at something like [Redcloth](http://redcloth.org/). With a text field. And for added bling you could give a ajaxy preview, just like stackoverflow does!. This would be a much more cleaner solution IMHO.

If you are going to use a WYSIWYG editor, take a look at [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and also the [Yahoo YUI2 Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/).

As for TinyMCE there is a [Rails plugin](http://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce) that would make things easier if you decide to use it.

Comment: In what way is the html generated messy? It would be good to have a example to backup what you are saying. I ask this because I am interested, not because I'm saying you are wrong.

Comment: well rite now, i dont have any idea about each one but am exploring these two and will see which one can give me easy implementation with better functionality.

Comment: i am too lazy to produce a example right now. But if you are interested, just try out any WYSIWYG editor out there, write a few lines. And look at the html it generates. Its valid HTML alright but it will have a plathora of uneeded tags. You can take a look at this link: http://redcloth.org/articles/wysi-dangerous-why-wysiwyg-editors-are-bad-for-your-website/

Answer (score 6):

A very promising one is the [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest TinyMCE which is really easy to implement. You just add an id for the textarea you want to use and then use that id in the configuration of TinyMCE. You could even configure TinyMCE to put a RTE on ALL textareas.

It's written in javascript so it doesn't matter what backend you use.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

And here's an example with source:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

Answer (score 0):

Aloha looks nice and has some very nice features, but I've run into some annoying bugs.  You may want to take a look at [Mercury](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frailscasts.com%2Fepisodes%2F296-mercury-editor&ei=SPCrUPnZMIe6qgG804GQBQ&usg=AFQjCNEPQV8p5tbn57StjZNMgeAoEUlUOg&sig2=vM-xMHqm4YmN9QMYeJ3e9w).